# .NET: Accessing static MVC controller method from View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I've got an .aspx page with this in it:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc" %>
<%= AssetController.ScriptTag("/js/Community/CommunityWizard.js")%>
```

And I have an `AssetController` class:

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Public Class AssetController
    Inherits Controller

    Public Shared Function ScriptTag(ByVal src As String) As String
        Return String.Format(
            "<script type='text/javascript' src='/js.mvc?src={0}&{1}'></script>", 
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(src), 
            New BuildVersion().ToString()
        )
    End Function
End Class
```

The project has a reference added to the 3.0.0.0 version of System.Web.Mvc assembly.

When I try to view the page in a browser, I get a HTTP 500 with this message:

> BC30007: Reference required to
>   assembly 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, 
>           Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   containing the base class 
>       'System.Web.Mvc.Controller'. Add one to your project.

What gives? I don't understand why I can use this controller everywhere in our ASP.NET Forms/MVC hybrid application, but not in a view.

**EDIT: In fact, when I type `<% System.Web.` into the .aspx view, `Mvc` doesn't even appear in Intellisense!**

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your app? Are you sure the MVC 3 reference on the project containing your views is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Was missing this in my view:

> <%@ Assembly Name="System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>

Comment: yeah, the error message was kinda telling you what the problem was xD

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the web.Config that usually goes in your /Views folder.